# ArcPad 10: Accessing the Geography information of a feature through ArcPad Studio (VB Script)

Tags: arcpad, fields-attributes, vbscript

I am trying to access the geography feature property of a feature being edited. I need to do it programatically (in order to auto populate a field using the geography) using VB Script. I cannot seem to figure out what the ArcPad object is that I want to access in the script. Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT

How do I access the Points Collection of an added feature in ArcPad studio?

Answer (score 2):

Dim objRS, objLayer, objShape, pointsCollection, centroid

Set objLayer = Map.SelectionLayer
Set objRS = objLayer.Records

objRS.Bookmark = Map.SelectionBookmark

Set objShape = objRS.Fields.Shape

pointsCollection = objShape.Parts.Item(1)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Have you looked at the help as there are plenty of examples? To access features within a FeatureClass you would use the RecordSet, have a look [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/sdk/scripting/index.html).

Comment: It turns out, I was trying to ask how to access the Points Collection of an added feature. But now I know how do to do that. Thank you.